Is it possible to install cgywin and wget for windows xp?
I need to run windows xp system and use cygwin and wget tools. Is it possible? I googled and some links are not working anymore.
Updated: I have made it work to instrall cygwin on xp systems by selecting the proper download links.

What are you really trying to do?   XP is a 20 year old operating system. Even Cygwin's home page mentions deprecating support for Windows 7.  Also, not a programming question....

Our product support XP operating system, so I need to set up the environment like this.

As the [tag:windows] tag description states: "GENERAL WINDOWS SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC." This is off-topic, as it has nothing to do with programming (and is a general Windows support question). Also, fyi Windows XP is well beyond EOL - your product is supporting an unsupported OS.

I do not know what cgywin is, but if you need usable wget in Windows XP, I suggest trying Wget for Windows which works with

Win32, i.e. MS-Windows 95 / 98 / ME / NT / 2000 / XP / 2003 / Vista /
2008 with msvcrt.dll and msvcp60.dll.

You might get installer (setup) or binaries which contain wget.exe in bin directory.

It works, just the wget version is low and not support TLS 2.0. So I use a modern machine to run the scripts and move to the old machine.

On this page, it seems the last version for XP is the v1.19.4
